# When jasmine-reporters used to generated output,it is in root directory not in specified directory

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

1. I used Jasmine-reporters to generate reporters,i specified the path where to generate the reporter file in config file,but the report is generated in root directory.

I added the following command in my config.file

```
onPrepare: function() {
    var jasmineReporters = require('C:/Users/KB_PRASHA_QA/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jasmine-reporters');


jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new jasmineReporters.NUnitXmlReporter ('C:/Users/KB_PRASHA_QA/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/example/outputdir', true, true)
);
}
```

2. In the above command true is mentioned twice after the path,that true indicates which thing?

Answer (score 1):

Answering your first question and referring to [`jasmine-reporters`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters) repository, you should be passing an object with `savePath` property to the reporter to have your report stored in a custom path. Here's how -

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new jasmineReporters.NUnitXmlReporter ({savePath: 'C:/Users/KB_PRASHA_QA/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/example/outputdir'})
);
```

[Here's an example implementation of it in the github repo](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/blob/master/test/NUnitXmlReporterSpec.js#L106).

As per your second question, i don't think you can just pass in an argument like `true` to the reporter, as most of the reporters identify an argument based on the property/key name. The github repo for `jasmine-reporters` points that you can pass the arguments with following properties for `NUnitXmlReporter` - `savePath`, `filename`, `reportName`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried as you said by giving savepath,but it showing synatx error.What may be the reason?

Comment: @Falcon i have removed the additional arguments (`true, true`) that you had provided. Updated code with the same. Can you try and check to see if you still get that error? Thanks